# How to delete the last page in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I am sure the question has been asked many times but I am still not able to delete the last page.

What I have tried:
Pressed Control+Shift+8 to get paragraph marks and have tried deleting the last paragraph mark but to no avail.

Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Ctrl+Shift+8 to show empty paragraph markers and verify that there are no empty paragraphs on the last page of your document. If there are, then place your cursor at the end of your final desired page and hold down the delete key until the last (blank) page goes away.

If you have a table at the very end of your document, Word insists on forcing a blank paragraph after tables. You cannot (to the best of my knowledge) remove this paragraph but you can modify it to incredibly small font and line heights to try forcing it to fit on the last desired page. Technically you can hide this empty paragraph using Ctrl+Shift+H but it doesn't always take, it won't completely disappear until you once again hide paragraph marks.

If that doesn't work, verify that you do not have more than one section. Under "Page Layout" go to "Page Setup" options and see if your "Section Start: New Page" has changed to Odd or Even page. If it has, you'll need to carefully work this out in order to not lose formatting. I cannot give specifics without knowing the existing formatting of your document.

Finally, if you are getting a blank page at the end of every document you print and have exhausted all other explanations, check the printer Properties to see whether there is a “separator page” option that has been enabled.

Comment: still can't do it...

Comment: no table at the end of the document. I can see the blank page in the print preview page as wel..

Comment: I would try the last paragraph of my revised answer first (separator page should be in printer properties), then check the third paragraph.

Comment: I can send you my document to see if what you can do..

Comment: figured it out?

Comment: I see the problem but haven't remedied it yet. There are multiple section breaks in the document but changing them to different break types or removing them directly destroys your formatting.  Still working on it...

Comment: Updated copy sent, let me know how that works for you. If it works, the problem was paragraph three from my answer above. It just wasn't quite as straight-forward in your particular case.

Comment: Using the delete key, instead of the backspace key, worked. That's it

Answer (score 1):

For documents that have a table at the end, hiding the final paragraph marker offers some advantages over formatting it with a tiny point size.  Although you cannot delete the blank paragraph that follows it, if you hide the paragraph marker itself by selecting it (to select it, position your cursor in the empty paragraph, then hold your Shift key and press your right arrow once), then selecting "Hidden" under the font properties, then at least the last page won't print.  And unless your display settings in Word are set to display hidden text, it will disappear from your screen also.

Formatting it with a tiny point size doesn't guarantee that the final page won't print.  It ***may*** be the case, but isn't always, that formatting it with a tiny point size will allow it to fit on the prior page, but if the table goes all the way to the margin, there may not be room for it, and so the final page will continue to print.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you want to delete the last page in a word document, I have an alternative approach for that.Just follow the steps given below :

1) Save the doc file as pdf.
2) Then open that particular file in Google Chrome or any browser in your PC.
3) You can see a print option on the right corner of it, if not just press `Ctrl+P` to enable the printer options.
4) `Change the destination` to `save as pdf`.
5) At the bottom of `change destination` you can find a `pages` option.
6) Give the page numbers as 1 to N-1.
7) Now click on save button and save it in your required destination folder.

Its done !!!! We successfully deleted the last page of our document and converted it into pdf.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Except the question doesn't say anything about wanting a PDF.

Comment: In general many of users convert their doc files into pdf and hence I suggested a solution related to pdf so that it might be helpful to some user who is having the same issue.

Ex: Creating a resume, most users convert it into pdf before sending.. I guess this might be helpful for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just worked this out.  You need to create a new line (can be blank) *after* the end of the table.  If you do that and press delete at the end of that line the extra page magically disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The bar on the left of the table will show white and grey spaces indicating the rows. Right at the bottom I can see a tiny white row indicated. An unwanted page follows. Click on the tiny white row indicator and drag it down. The unwanted page disappears.